# pass value in global variable from client to server Lightswitch

Tags: c#, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a two tier VisualStudio C# Lightswitch application that i'd like to pass a variable from the client to server.

**Problem:**
When i try running my application the global variable `global.WorkOrder` is always null.  I've tried commenting out all the class references on the server and hardcoded a constant string into `global.WorkOrder` on the client....but it remains null. Here's some code.

Client:

```
public partial class AddPart
{
    partial void Input_Changed()
    {
      UserCode.Globals global = new UserCode.Globals();
      global.WorkOrder = parts[7];
```

Server:

```
namespace LightSwitchApplication
{
    public partial class DataService
    {
        partial void Instances_Inserted(Instance entity)
        {
            UserCode.Globals global = new UserCode.Globals();
            InstanceInfo w = this.DataWorkspace.AUTOData.InstanceInfoes.AddNew();
            w.InfoContent = global.WorkOrder;
```

I've also created a Class1 that lives on the server in a UserGroup folder.  The class has been 'linked' on the client side.

Class:

```
namespace LightSwitchApplication.UserCode
{
    public class Globals
    {
            public string WorkOrder { get; set; }
```

The code compiles without errors but something isn't correct.  What am I doing wrong?  Sorry for the beginner question, and please let me know if you need more information to help. Thanks!

Comment: As a troubleshooting effort i went in the class and hardcoded `public string Workorder = "Mike"`.  This pushes Mike out to both client and server variable declarations, even though in the client i've got `global.WorkOrder = parts[7]`.  parts[7] definitely has a value but global.Workorder is still not being written too on the client.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my global variable is working fine, I have another issue with a line of code that commits the record entry to my database.  I execute the commit on the client before the server is data is committed.  As soon as i commit the variable it becomes null.  This is more of a code structure thing with the two tier system that i need to figure out.